# Error local variable has been referenced before assignment

Tags: python, class, web-scraping

I am new to the stackoverflow community, and new to programming in general. One of my first projects is to build a web scraper to see if I can collect market data. In attempting to build this, I keep getting stuck with an unbound local error. I am aware that this has something to do with how I am instantiating my class and how I am referencing the variable,**strong text** but not sure how to trouble shoot it..

```
class Stock:
    def __init__(self,symbol,company):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.company = company
        self.data = []
            
            
    
    def query_stock_symbol(self):
        wait_time = round(max(5, 10 +random.gauss(0,3)), 2)
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        
        
        url = 'https://www.barrons.com/quote/stock/us/xnys/%s?mod=DNH_S'  % (self.symbol)
        page = requests.get(url)
        if page.status_code == 403 or page.status_code == 404:
            url = 'https://www.barrons.com/quote/stock/us/xnas/%s?mod=DNH_S' % (self.symbol)
       
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'
        headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
        req = urllib.request.Request(url,headers=headers)
        
        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        except urllib.error.URLError as e:
            print(e.reason)
           
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
           
        
#         Finding stock price
        for a in self.soup.findAll('span',{'class':'market_price'}):
            stock_price_str = a.text.replace(',','')
            if stock_price_str != 'N/A':
                self.stock_price = float(stock_price_str)
            else:
                self.stock_price = None
```

The error I receive is such

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-277-f9c756bf109f> in <module>
      1 x = Stock('CRM','Salesforce')
----> 2 x.query_stock_symbol()
      3 

<ipython-input-276-1f910b91d713> in query_stock_symbol(self)
     26             print(e.reason)
     27 
---> 28         self.soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
     29 
     30 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment
```


Thanks for all your time and consideration, I really do appreciate it
````

Comment: Please [edit] all code and errors into the question itself as text.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO :) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you can find a guide to write a good question and increase your chances to get a good answer. For example, you should add your code here (not an image), so that other users can easily reproduce errors or problem in your code.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the tips, still trying to get a hang of everything, but hoping that this is more in line with expectations.

Comment: How about this `query_stock_symbol(self,response="")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have `response` declared in a `try` block while you attempt to use it *outside* of that block, you could either:

1- declare `response` globally before using it inside the `try` block, like this:

```
try:
    global response
    response = ...
except ...:
    ...
self.soup = ....
```

2- instantiate the `Soup` object inside the `try` block below the `response` assignment like this:

```
try:
    response = ...
    self.soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
```

or

3- declare the `response` variable before the `try` block, this is a more problematic approach and could lead to problems when response is not assigned correctly (like when the `exception` is raised), however if you decide to go with this, you could do something like this:

```
response = None
try:
    response = ...
except ...:
    .....
self.soup = ...
```

Always remember that **locally declared variables**, like in a `try` block, an `if` block, an `else` block, etc. are not accessible outside of said block, they are **local** to that **block**

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I appreciate it, however; when I try the 1st edit you suggested, I am receiving an error saying my object stock now does not have soup, as I believe according to your previous remarks soup is now local to that try block. How would I get around this?

Comment: Ah yes, my fault here for not foreseeing that here, I think the optimal solution would be then to use the keyword `global`, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the error raised by `urllib.request.urlopen`: if this method raises an error you only print it and keep on executing your code. But, this means that all the instructions in the try block could have not been executed and that `response` has not defined.

For example, this code works as expected:

```py
try:
    a = 10
except Exception:
    print(e)

print(a)
```

The output is:

```sh
10
```

so the variable `a` is defined when you print it; on the other hand, this code raises an error like the one you are experimenting:

```py
try:
    a = 10 / 0
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

print(a)
```

```sh
division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try_catch_example.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(a)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

So, the real problem is that you have to decide what to do when something in the `try` block fails.

In your case, printing the error is not enough; you should, probably, interrupt the method, raising a warning or reraising a more 'commented' error:

```py
        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        except urllib.error.URLError as e:
            print('Something wrong with urlopen! Read carefully the reason of the error')
            print(f'req: {req}')
            print(e.reason)
            raise RuntimeError('Failed to open the required url') from exc
```

Comment: thank you so much for the feedback, this is extremely helpful and will adjust my code accordingly to handle the exceptions.