# I am trying to code blackjack for fun and i get this error local variable 'first_hit' referenced before assignment on line: 32

Tags: python, blackjack

I am coding in codesters/python bc thats what my school is teaching me on and im trying to code in the hit button. I originally had it where there were no if statements but i realized i might need to hit 2 times i tried this and i get the error message "local variable 'first_hit' referenced before assignment on line: 32"
if first_hit == True:

This happens when i click the hit button the first time

```
first_hit = True
def click(hit_button):
    if first_hit == True:
        player3 = random.choice(cards)
        player3disp = codesters.Display(player3, 50, -150)
        player_total = player1 + player2 + player3
        playertotaldisp.update(player_total)
        first_hit = False
        stage.wait(1)
    elif first_hit == False:
        player4 = random.choice(cards)
        player4disp = codesters.Display(player4, 150, -150)
        player_total = player1 + player2 + player3 + player4
        playertotaldisp.update(player_total)
    
hit_button.event_click(click)
```

Comment: You need to define ```first_hit``` as a **global** variable inside your function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error local variable has been referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636186/error-local-variable-has-been-referenced-before-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Normally a variable will be local meaning that once you are in a new scope (In this case your function) Python won't "see" the variable.

To make your variable accessible from all scopes you use `global first_hit` before the first reference.

Since you'll often start to get problems finding new names for variables when you use global variables, it is often a good idea to put things that will reference each other in a class.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to python so i didn't know about global variables or scopes.